# CasperJS with SpookyJS hanging after getting page content

Tags: node.js, casperjs, spookyjs

I am using CasperJS and SpookyJS to navigate to a page, parse the page HTML, and then take some action depending on the HTML of the parsed page.

However, pulling HTML from the page blocks all further `spookyInstance.then` calls from executing. However, when I replace the HTML fetching code with any other code, subsequent `.then` calls execute without issue.

Current Code:

```
spookyInstance.then( function () {
  // 'getPageContent()' can be replaced with 'getHTML('body'), 'this.page.content' to the same effect
  this.emit( 'requestParserReturn', this.getPageContent() );
});
```

Replacement code that works:

```
spookyInstance.then( function () {
  this.emit( 'requestParserReturn', '<p>arbitrary HTML</p>' );
});
```

Is there something I'm missing, here? Is there something about interacting with the page HTML itself that prevents further execution?

I'm on the latest SpookyJS (0.2.5) and CapserJS (1.1-beta3). All help would be appreciated.

Comment: A comment from [@KevinGagnon](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4962411/kevin-gagnon) who can't post a comment so posted an answer instead): "*Can we see the event code ?*".